# Any WordPress theme & plugin for the blog with a subscription plan?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, blogs

This is about Webdesign & development.

My client wants the magazine website with a subscription plan. He wants to post a few topics on the website if visitors want to read all the topics they have to buy a subscription.

Only the subscriber can read all the topics in the magazine.

I am a medium level Wordpress developer I have no idea about how to do.

I am not able to find any competitors or reference websites.

Can someone please suggest a theme or plugins for this?

Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Google Search 'wordpress subscription plugin'. There are many options - you can research which is best suited/closest to your needs. You will most likely need to do some custom coding as per your exact requirements.

Answer (score 0):

**Use any Membership control plugin then restrice content to registered users only.
i will recommend this plugin but you are free to choose the sutiubale one for you.**
https://ar.wordpress.org/plugins/ultimate-member/